# What's the best way to turn some spaced integers to an array in C using getchar()? Given the max no of elements = 5

Tags: arrays, c, getchar

Problem: To turn spaced integers into an array of size 5. If there are less than five elements, make the remaining 0.

The input consists of positive integers only and is taken through the command line 
The maximum no of elements entered = 5 
Sample Input:

```
>>>1 2 3 4
```

It should give me an array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 0}

Sample Input 2:

```
>>>1 2 3 4 5
```

It gives me an array = {1,2,3,4,5}

My code:

```
int getnum(){
    char c;
    int i = 0, sum = -1;
    c = getchar();
    while ((c != '\n') && (c != ' ')){
        if (sum == -1)
            sum ++;
        i = c - '0';
        sum = 10 * sum + i;
        c = getchar();
    }
    return sum;
}

int main(){
    int count = 0, arr[5], j = 0;
    char c = getnum();
    while (c != -1){
        arr[count] = c;
        count ++;
        c = getnum();
    }
    for(j = count; j < 5; j++)
        arr[j] = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

My code requires two newline characters to work (i.e. after entering the requires numbers, if I press enter twice, the program gives the output) whereas I want the output by just pressing enter once. What's the easiest way to modify the code to make it work?

Comment: You're not checking for EOF...

Comment: @MarkNunberg I'm executing the file in the terminal. And I'm entering the values manually. I don't understand why I need to check for EOF since the while loop will terminate after we press enter twice (or enter two newline characters).

Comment: @user3121023 I've been told to use `getchar`. Doesn't the use of `fgets` make it more complicated?

Comment: Use `fgets()` to read a line of user input, then process the string.  `int n = sscanf(buf, "%d%d%d%d%d", ...`

Comment: Eventually, you'll read until EOF [particularly, if you do: `./myprogram < input.txt`]. So, what you want in `getnum` is: `while ((c != '\n') && (c != ' ') && (c != EOF))`. Otherwise, you'll loop infinitely on the `EOF` value. Yes, if you add an extra newline, you'll stop with your original code [but that's what you wanted to avoid].

Comment: Something to try: `int c;` `while ((c = getnum()) != -1)` and remove the existing calls to `getnum`.